# convert funcion global js to vuejs global, vue laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

My function js just show color border required, and if input any place has something change color.
in javascript work good but in vue no work.

I need to use this function in vue. anyplace, any component of vue

**app.js**

```
$('.req' ).on('keyup', function() {
  let val = this.value
  val = $.trim(val)
  if(val==""){
    $(this).removeClass('valid');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('valid');
  }
});

$('.req').change(function() {
  let val = this.value
  val = $.trim(val)
  if(val==""){
    $(this).removeClass('valid');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('valid');
  }
})
```

**Anyplace.blade.php**

```
<form>
    <input type="text"  class="req form-control " name="last_name">
</form>
```

**app.css**

```
.valid{
    border-left: 2px solid #9cff2b !important;
}
.req{
    border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

**component-example.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">papa</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        papa. esto viene del hijo {{ messaje }}
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" v-model="modelo" class="req ">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hijo :numero=modelo  @verInfo="recibirpapa" > </hijo>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component papa.')
        },
        data(){
                return{
                    modelo:"",
                    messaje:''
                }
        },methods:{
                recibirpapa(valor){
                    this.messaje = valor;
                }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery syntax in vue. That's why it's not working. 
Try reading [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/jquery-vue-javascript/) article on how to convert a jQuery project to Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. include `<req-input></req-input>` anywhere you want.

```js
Vue.component('req-input', {
    template: '#req-input-template',
  props: {
    value: {
        type: [String, Number],
      default: ""
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
         currentValue: "",
       valid: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
        handler(value) {
                const string = value.trim()
        if (string=="") {
            this.valid = false
        } else {
            this.valid = true
        }
        
        this.currentValue = value
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput() {
        this.$emit("input", this.currentValue);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        modelo: ""
  },
})
```

```css
.valid {
  border-left: 2px solid #9cff2b !important;
}

.req{
    border-left: 2px solid red;
}

.form-control:focus {
  outline: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <req-input v-model="modelo"></req-input>
  modelo: {{ modelo }}
  
  <script type="text/x-template" id="req-input-template">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      v-model="currentValue"
      @input="handleInput"
      :class="['form-control req', { 'valid': valid }]" />
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent!! your answer, but if i am using vue component like `Vue.component('req-input', require('./components/reqInput.vue').default);` , and the last part I need to use always or what is mean this? sorry im new in it;  this last part: `<input 
      type="text" 
      v-model="currentValue"
      @input="handleInput"
      :class="['form-control req', { 'valid': valid }]" />` how can I add or what mean this.?